# How to get the Google Voice Number in Android

Tags: google-voice

I am trying to work on a project that requires google voice number. Is there a way that I can pull the google voice number without letting the user to enter it? If yes, then could anyone please explain how this can be done?? I would really appreciate if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

From a brief search, looks like yes, as long as you have the right permission:

[API for Fetching the Google Voice Configuration on Android](http://kellinwood.blogspot.com/2013/05/api-for-fetching-google-voice.html)